# Link to download apache http server for 64bit windows.

Tags: apache

I found a link downloading apache http server for 32 bit windows and not for 64 bit. can anyone give me the link to download for 64bit.Please help me..

Comment: https://www.apachelounge.com/download/

Answer (score 11):

From: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/FAQ#Where_can_I_download_.28certified.29_64_bit_Apache_httpd_binaries_for_Windows.3F

> Where can I download (certified) 64 bit Apache httpd binaries for
>   Windows?
>
> Right now, there are none. The Apache Software Foundation produces
>   Open Source Software. The 32 bit binaries provided are a courtesy of
>   the community members.

Though there are some unofficial e.g. http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/, but I have no idea if they can be trusted.

Answer (score 7):

An unofficial 64-bit Windows build is available [from Apache Lounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/).

Answer (score 4):

Check out the link given it has Apache HTTP Server 2.4.2 x86 and x64 Windows Installers http://www.anindya.com/apache-http-server-2-4-2-x86-and-x64-windows-installers/

Answer (score 1):

you can find multiple options listed at 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#down

ApacheHaus
Apache Lounge
BitNami WAMP Stack
WampServer
XAMPP